# Generating unique type identifier at compile time

Tags: c++

I need a way to generate a unique identifier (either string or integer) for any type for use in a set of template functions. The documentation for `type_info::name()` says it *may or may not be different for different types*, which worries me since I need to rely on them being unique. The `hash_code` probably isn't unique, either (judging by the name, I haven't looked at what the standard has to say on this).

My question mainly is, in what cases could `typeid(T).name()` be *not* unique?

Since types can come from different (DLL) modules, I can't simply use a global counter and a template static function. Thread safety isn't an issue though, since the functions that may require a type ID are guaranteed to only be called by one thread at a time.

Comment: Convert the address of the `type_info` to string, or a suitably-sized integer? Won't work across different executions of course.

Comment: Is the address guaranteed to be different for different types (and same for same types, for all I know it could always return the same struct with different values in it, or always return a new struct)?

Comment: Checking the standard there's no guarantee that you'll always get the same object back (although if you do get different objects they must compare equal). But 18.7.1/8 in the C++11 standard says that you *should* get different `hash_code` values for different types. (Sadly "should" is not a guarantee.)

Comment: Hence thread safety is no issue: Id generate() { static Id result; return ++result; } // But this might be to simple.

Comment: That's why I mentioned having multiple DLL modules. Every module will have its own `static result`, which will result in collisions. I haven't noticed the part that mentions that `hash_code()` should be different; if its a stronger guarantee than for `name()`, then I'll take it.

Answer (score 3):

> I need a way to generate a unique identifier (either string or
>   integer) for any type for use in a set of template functions.

Would something along these lines help?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class unique_id {
  static char type_id;
public:
  static uintptr_t get_ID() { return reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&type_id); }
};

template <typename T>
char unique_id<T>::type_id;

struct { } s;

int main() {
  cout << unique_id<int          >::get_ID() << endl;
  cout << unique_id<double       >::get_ID() << endl;
  cout << unique_id<decltype(s)  >::get_ID() << endl;
  cout << unique_id<size_t       >::get_ID() << endl;
  cout << unique_id<unsigned long>::get_ID() << endl; 
}
```

There is *something similar* in the LLVM codebase as it doesn't use RTTI. However, I have failed to find the description of that trick. Even 30 minutes of googling didn't help; I have given up.

> My question mainly is, in what cases could typeid(T).name() be not unique?

<strike>I don't know the answer to that one. My guess is that the standard doesn't mandate that; of course, it doesn't answer the questions why.</strike>

OK, see [Michael J's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20869822/341970).

---

**UPDATE:** As for `std::type_info::name()`, it seems like there is no *guarantee* by the standard; the returned string can be identical for several types and change between invocations of the same program.

One option is to dive into implementation defined land: I would simply test it on the types I care about and on all platforms and compiler that I care about. If it works fine then I would probably risk it.

However, there are `std::type_info::operator==` and `std::type_info::operator!=` which may solve your problem: You can distinguish types from each other and it even seems to be guaranteed. Does it matter in your application whether you compare strings or type_info objects?

Comment: Other ways to implement the same idea: [without the function call](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03c626c0bd03831c) and [as a simple funcion](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f18ee933d1585539).

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Thanks, yes, there are a number of variations of this thing. I would have to see how it is used in the client code to pick one of the possible variations. I see potential difficulties with each of the approaches; it really depends on the client code which one to use.

Comment: It wouldn't work with multiple DLL modules, as each of them will have its own `unique_id<int>::type_id`.

Comment: @riv Hmm. Interesting. **Your use case is not clear to me.** Would it be possible to have one DLL that knows all the type IDs and let everyone else ask this DLL for the IDs of the types? The types can still come from different DLLs, the only thing you need to enforce is that only one DLL knows the IDs. If it is not possible then please clarify the use case.

Comment: The application revolves around a Lua engine, and the only DLL shared between modules is the basic interpreter. The main program loads the required modules at run-time, and calls their initialization function to populate the Lua state. The modules share a small amount of code from a few header files, one of which provides basic functions to bind methods to structs, and I wanted to avoid having to explicitly specify type information. Regarding this answer, you obviously can't export a template function/class, so it won't work regardless of my use case.

Comment: @riv Then, perhaps, it is not possible to achieve what you want in a standard conforming and guaranteed way.

Comment: That's why I was trying to find out in which cases `typeid(T).name` can return a non-unique name. As long as it works for simple structs with no templates/typedefs, it should be fine.

Comment: Strings and integers can be used as keys for lua tables; indexing by  user defined objects will compare them as pointers. Using a custom hashtable to map `type_info` to integers would probably be even less dll-safe. That said, it seems that I'd settle for `typeid(T).name`, or simply use a static value if that causes problems.

Comment: @riv OK, unfortunately I am not familiar with lua. Yes, that's what I suggested in the update, test `typeid(T).name()` and if it works for you (even if not guaranteed) then probably that is the best choice given your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes more than one name can refer to the same type.  Hopefully the following example will give you the idea

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    class Foo
    {
    };
    class Bar : public Foo
    {
    };
    typedef int my_int;
    std::cout << "int8_t        = " << typeid(int8_t).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int16_t       = " << typeid(int16_t).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int32_t       = " << typeid(int32_t).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int64_t       = " << typeid(int64_t).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "short         = " << typeid(short).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "short int     = " << typeid(short int).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int           = " << typeid(int).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "long          = " << typeid(long).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "long int      = " << typeid(long int).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "long long     = " << typeid(long long).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "long long int = " << typeid(long long int).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "my_int        = " << typeid(my_int).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Foo           = " << typeid(Foo).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bar           = " << typeid(Bar).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
int8_t        = signed char
int16_t       = short
int32_t       = int
int64_t       = __int64
short         = short
short int     = short
int           = int
long          = long
long int      = long
long long     = __int64
long long int = __int64
my_int        = int
Foo           = ?AVFoo@?1?main@
Bar           = ?AVBar@?1?main@
```

Comment: Makes sense, though I'm not planning to use it for basic types. As long as it works correctly for structs/classes, I'm happy with it.